# Os botões adicionados por debaixo do ReciclerView não aparecem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Estou usando um LinearLayout com uma ReciclerView e 3 botões debaixo dela.

Estou a fazer assim, mas a ReciclerView ocupa a tela toda e os botões não aparecem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/salmao"
    tools:context="br.com.robson.boascompras.ListasComprasActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/editar"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/excluir"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nova_lista"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não pode usar `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, numa RecyclerView ou ListView, quando o número de itens excede o tamanho da tela.

`wrap_content` quer dizer "torne-me grande o suficiente para apresentar todo o meu conteúdo".
Quando o espaço necessário é maior que a tela, a RecyclerView ocupa-a toda, "empurrando" tudo o que está por debaixo dela para fora da tela.

Mude `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` para `android:layout_height="0p"` e atribua-lhe um peso com `android:layout_weight`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/salmao"
    tools:context="br.com.robson.boascompras.ListasComprasActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/editar"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/excluir"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nova_lista"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! resolveu o meu problema!
Mas eu fiquei com uma dúvida, eu coloquei "android:layout_height="wrap_content" por que na minha lógica eu não sei quantos elementos serão colocados na lista, então seria ajustado de acordo com o conteúdo( a quantidade de itens), por que essa lógica não é válida?

Comment: A razão é essa mesma ser  "ajustado de acordo com o conteúdo( a quantidade de itens)", como o espaço necessário para apresentar o conteúdo é maior que a tela, os botões são "empurrados" para baixo não ficando visíveis.